# Building lambda-expression using expression templates in Cuda

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, lambda

I'm developing a CUDA application which requires me to pass in some arbitrary function to the CUDA kernel. Since declaring a function pointer for each possible situation and pass them to the kernel would be too much of a hassle (>50 different functions), and all of them are compositions of elementary functions like `sin(x)/y`, I'd like to have some minimal Lambda-Expression functionality for CUDA kernels. Since C++11 features are not supported by device code yet (as far as I know), and I failed to find any relevant information online, I decided to teach myself expression templates and implement some simple lambda-expression rules to pass into kernels.

I've come up with the following code, which is kind of a minimal implementation that compiles on NVCC and runs fine. However, going down this path I can only implement functions with 1 variable. Is there any way to extend my code to handle function composites like `sin(_x) + _y`?

Thanks in advance!

```
#include<math.h>

#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define HOST_DEVICE __host__ __device__
#else
#define HOST_DEVICE
#endif

struct Id {};

template <typename Op, typename Left, typename Right>
struct BinaryOp
{
    Left left;
    Right right;
    HOST_DEVICE BinaryOp(Left t1, Right t2) : left(t1), right(t2) {}

    HOST_DEVICE double operator() (double x) {
        return Op::apply(left(x), right(x));
    }
};

template <typename Op, typename Arg>
struct UnaryOp
{
    Arg arg;
    HOST_DEVICE UnaryOp(Arg t1) : arg(t1) {}

    HOST_DEVICE double operator() (double x) {
        return Op::apply(arg(x));
    }
};

template <>
struct UnaryOp<Id, double>
{
    HOST_DEVICE UnaryOp() {}
    HOST_DEVICE double operator() (double x) {
        return x;
    }
};

struct Sin
{
    HOST_DEVICE static double apply(double x) {
        return sin(x);
    }
};

struct Plus
{
    HOST_DEVICE static double apply(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

template <typename Left, typename Right>
BinaryOp<Plus, Left, Right> operator+ (Left lhs, Right rhs) {
    return BinaryOp<Plus, Left, Right>(lhs, rhs);
}

template <typename Arg>
UnaryOp<Sin, Arg> _sin(Arg arg) {
    return UnaryOp<Sin, Arg>(arg);
}

template <class T>
__global__ void test(T func, double x) {
    printf("%e\n", func(x));
}

int main () 
{
    UnaryOp<Id, double> _x;
    double x = 1.0;
    test<<<1, 1>>>(_sin(_x) + _x, x);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();  // Needed or the host will return before kernel is finished
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at [expression templates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates).

Comment: @Constructor Thanks, but I have read that in detail, and came up with my own code of implementing the expression template. But I don't think that page has enough information for what I'd like to do: constructing lambda expressions for more than 1 variable.

Comment: Can you explain to me why what you've done is more simple than just function pointers? I really want to know.  I've been staring at your code for 2 days and I still don't see the advantage

Comment: @portforwardpodcast Yes, in principle I can define a device function for all possible combinations of elementary functions that I need to use, and pass a pointer to the kernel as needed. However, whenever I decide I need, say, f1(x, y) * f2(x, y), I'll need to define a new device function, and as a result the code will be cluttered with a bunch of small functions that I may use. Another problem is that Cuda will not inline device functions if passed in as a function pointer, which results in a performance decrease.

Answer (score 1):

So I've spent some time after asking the question and hacked up a solution. It's ugly but it works for myself. Here is the modified code that supports up to 3 free variables. More variables can be hard-coded but I don't have the need for my project at the moment.

```
#include<math.h>

#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define HOST_DEVICE __host__ __device__
#else
#define HOST_DEVICE
#endif

struct Id {};

template <typename Op, typename Left, typename Right>
struct BinaryOp
{
    Left left;
    Right right;
    HOST_DEVICE BinaryOp(Left t1, Right t2) : left(t1), right(t2) {}

    HOST_DEVICE double operator() (double x1, double x2 = 0.0, double x3 = 0.0) {
        return Op::apply(left(x1, x2, x3), right(x1, x2, x3));
    }
};

template <typename Op, typename Arg>
struct UnaryOp
{
    Arg arg;
    HOST_DEVICE UnaryOp(Arg t1) : arg(t1) {}

    HOST_DEVICE double operator() (double x1, double x2 = 0.0, double x3 = 0.0) {
        return Op::apply(arg(x1, x2, x3));
    }
};

template <int argnum>
struct Var
{
    HOST_DEVICE Var() {}
    HOST_DEVICE double operator() (double x1, double x2 = 0.0, double x3 = 0.0) {
        if (1 == argnum) return x1;
        else if (2 == argnum) return x2;
        else return x3;
    }
};

struct Sin
{
    HOST_DEVICE static double apply(double x) {
        return sin(x);
    }
};

struct Plus
{
    HOST_DEVICE static double apply(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
};

template <typename Left, typename Right>
BinaryOp<Plus, Left, Right> operator+ (Left lhs, Right rhs) {
    return BinaryOp<Plus, Left, Right>(lhs, rhs);
}

template <typename Arg>
UnaryOp<Sin, Arg> _sin(Arg arg) {
    return UnaryOp<Sin, Arg>(arg);
}

template <class T>
__global__ void test(T func, double x, double y, double z = 0.0) {
    printf("%e\n", func(x, y));
}

Var<1> _x;
Var<2> _y;

int main () 
{
    test<<<1, 1>>>(_sin(_x) + _y, 1.0, 2.0);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();  // Needed or the host will return before kernel is finished
    return 0;
}
```

This is clearly an ugly hack. The lambda expression only works with `double` (or types that can be converted to `double`). However I can't imagine a way to get around that at the moment. Hopefully NVCC can support c++11 features soon so that I don't need this kind of  hack anymore.

It would be greatly appreciated if anyone can show me a better solution, either a library or a better way of hacking this together. Thanks for any help!